# Database table modeling - columns inheritance

Tags: mysql, database, inheritance, rdbms, modeling

I want to have two tables:

```
[Table1]         [Table2]
id1              id2
createdon        createdon
createdby        createdby
column1a         column2
column1b
```

One can see that both tables do have 'createdon' and 'createdby' columns. Similar thing is with my other tables. Is there a way to model and implement database tables structure with columns inheritance (like I would do it with class properties in OOP). Conceptually what I mean: I'd like to create one super table:

```
[Supertable]
createdon
createdby
```

and make that Table10 and Table20 extend Supertable. That way I wouldn't have to create 'createdon' and 'createdby' columns for each particular table because they would be inherited from super table.

```
[Table10]  extends  [Supertable]   results in wanted   [Table1]
id1                 createdon                          id1
column1a            createdby                          createdon
column1b                                               createdby
                                                       column1a
                                                       column1b

[Table20]  extends  [Supertable]   results in wanted   [Table2]
id2                 createdon                          id2
column2             createdby                          createdon
                                                       createdby
                                                       column2
```

So Table10, Table20 and Supertabe are just structures inside RDBMS and Table1 and Table2 is that what database users see as final tables when they access database. Is something like this possible in MySQL (or in any other RDBMS)?

Comment: Postgres supports table inheritance. MySQL does not.

Answer (score 0):

From a pure modeling perspective... why shouldn't it be possible?

Your table structure would then look like this (I've adapted your syntax):

```
[Table1]       [Table2]
id1            id2
column1a       column2
column1b
```

...and...

```
[Table0]
table   <- either Table1 or Table2
id      <- either the value id1 or id2
createdon
createdby
```

But the big question is... would you benefit by that in your application? I cannot answer that question without looking way deeper in what you're about to do.

Comment: Maybe I was missundersood in my question or I don't understand your answer therefore I reformulated my question.

Comment: Please don't mistake RDBMS für ORDBMS. What you want to archieve is possible, but not through the means of a real "extension" of tables like you're maybe used to from ORDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

You can also link table together with associations keys:

```
[supertable]
id
createdon
createdby

[Table1]  
id1  
supertable_id      
column1a    
column1b
```

This is not exactly what you are looking for but can be useful.